# Elisp - Avoid prompt in interactive function

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm trying to call the following org-mode function to insert the current timestamp in the buffer. The function is called by a script.

```
(org-time-stamp-inactive)
```

This, as expected, brings up a prompt asking for the date to use for the timestamp. But I want to skip the prompt and insert the timestamp directly. Is that possible at all? Haven't found anything that could help me.

Comment: Check the documentation, and see if it takes the timestamp as an argument. Then pass the argument: `(org-time-stamp-inactive your-time-stamp)`

Comment: It looks like it doesn't, so I guess it's a dead end.

Comment: FWIW, the Org code here does not look wonderful. It should be possible (easy) to use such a function non-interactively. And the doc is also not up to par. The doc for such commands should say clearly that it prompts the user. And it should of course *describe each parameter*. If I were an Org user I would submit a bug report...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should insert the current inactive time stamp:

```
(org-insert-time-stamp nil nil t)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I've used the following to insert a timestamp with the current time too.
    (org-insert-time-stamp nil t t)

Answer (score 2):

`org-time-stamp` unconditionally¹ calls `org-read-date` to prompt the user for a date. You can't pass a date. But you can [locally bind](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/cl.html#index-flet-173) `org-read-date` to a function that returns the date that you want to use.

```
(require 'cl)
(flet ((org-read-date (org-with-time &rest args)
         (format-time-string (if org-with-time "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "%Y-%m-%d")
                             (current-time))))
  (org-time-stamp-inactive with-time))
```

¹  <sub>Except sometimes when there is already a time stamp, but that's no help.</sub>

Comment: Interesting approach. But flet isn't defined on my emacs for some reason :/

Comment: @fullmontis Oh, yes. `flet` is part of the `cl` library which you need to load explicitly. It's bundled with Emacs.

Comment: @fullmontis `with-time` comes from the part of your script that you haven't shown. It's whatever you're passing as the argument to `org-time-stamp-inactive`.

Comment: Note that `cl` and thus `flet` are obsolete, and superseded by `cl-lib`.  Modern Emacs Lisp code should use `cl-lib` with [Generalized Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generalized-Variables.html) to make temporary function overrides, i.e. bind the `symbol-function` cell with `cl-letf` ([example](https://github.com/rejeep/shut-up.el/blob/bafd5be3a6edb20fa9022b496a42f06f3d85748b/shut-up.el#L114)).

Comment: @lunaryorn Emacs 23 (which doesn't have `cl-lib`) is far from obsolete.

Comment: @Gilles I'd consider Emacs 23 as obsolete, but YMMV obviously.  In any case, I was obviously talking about the state of affairs in the latest stable release and upcoming Emacs 24.4.  Code for older Emacs versions is not exactly “modern”, is it?

Comment: @lunaryorn There's a difference between modern and obsolete. Unless the question calls for it, I normally write answers that are useful to people out there right now. Many existing systems still run Emacs 23, for example Debian stable, RHEL/CentOS, and I think OSX if not using an external package source. Ubuntu LTS switched last month. It takes years for a software version to become obsolete — most users don't upgrade often. Given that `cl` still works in Emacs 24 and that its sole defect is the imperfect compatibility with Common Lisp, there's no urgency to stop using it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating the timestamp from scratch with the following call:

```
  (insert (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a]"))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can find the answer in documentation for similar function `(org-time-stamp)`

> [...] With two universal prefix arguments, insert an active timestamp
>   with the current time without prompting the user. [...]

So.. all you need to do is press `C-u C-u` before you invoke the function (for example `C-u C-u M-x org-time-stamp-inactive RET`)

Comment: I know that :) But I don't know how to do this when calling the function from a script. And I also wanted to know if it is possible more in general to avoid prompts in interactive functions.

Comment: Oh, OK. I'm not sure if there's a more general way of doing it, but there's a quic hack if you want to avoid having to insert universal argument: `(defun my-org-time-stamp ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-prefix-arg '(16)))
    (call-interactively 'org-time-stamp)))` This would also work in a script.

Comment: To insert inactive timestamp the last call in that function should be `(call-interactively 'org-time-stamp-inactive)`

Comment: no dice, still inserts the timestamp as active. I guess it's a bug. Oh well, thanks anyway :)

Comment: IIRC that bug was fixed a few weeks ago. At least I reported a very similar one. Anyway, using `(org-time-stamp-inactive '(16))` should be (almost) equivalent to the let form above.